# Regex Python "if number followed by alphabetical character"

Tags: python, regex

I have a .txt file with a big number of documents in it. Every documentstarts with:

```
                               11 of 500 DOCUMENTS
```

Numbers are obviously different. 31 spaces before the number (if that matters).
Unfortunately, I'm horrible with regex. How can I split these documents with regex?

Comment: What should the output of this be?  Do you want to split the file up into 500 files?

Comment: I have a python script that does some analysis on the text, however, I need it performed on one document at a time, not the whole batch.

Comment: I don't understand what the program is supposed to do in order to prepare the document for analysis.  Should it split the text up into 500 segments, retrieve a specified segment or what?  What is the desired input and output of the function you are having trouble with?

Comment: Yes, I want to split the document into 500 segments and then perform analysis on each segment one by one.

Comment: If you are horrible at regex, you shouldn't be asking other people to solve the problem for you. You'll end up with code you don't understand. Instead, use this as an excuse to learn regular expressions. One afternoon of study is about all it takes to get a good fundamental understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to extract the number of documents, this should be as simple as matching one or more digits `\d+` and using [saving groups](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping). Example:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = "                               11 of 500 DOCUMENTS"

In [3]: match = re.search(r"(\d+) of (\d+) DOCUMENTS", s)
In [4]: match.group(1)
Out[4]: '11'

In [4]: match.group(2)
Out[4]: '500'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need regexes for this. It seems like you can recognize the line easily enough with

```
line.startswith(31*' ')
```

or with

```
line.endswith('of 500 DOCUMENTS\n')
```

or with both, if you're a belt-and-suspenders man.  Assuming that there's no problem reading the file one line at a time, can't you do something along the lines of

```
document = []
for line in open('500docs.txt'):
    if line.startswith(31*' '):
       if document:
          analyze(document)
          document = []
       else:
          document.append(line)
```

This doesn't handle the last document in the file, so you need an `analyze(document)` outside the loop also.

Will this work for you, do you think?